# Getting JS Error (for - event.srcElement.id) in WebForm

Tags: asp.net

I am building a dynamic user control (ascx) which contains a placeholder. Inside the placeholder, there will be n tables. Inside each table, in one of the cells i have the link button as below.

HyperLink lnkButton = new HyperLink(); 
lnkButton.ID = "lnkButton_" + ID.ToString(); 
lnkButton.Text = tstText; 
lnkButton.NavigateUrl = "javascript:JS_Click();";

I have to call a JS function on the link button click (no postback).

In the JS function, i have to get the id of the control that invoked that JS function. In this case, it will be link button. I am writing the below code in the JS Function:

var ctrl = event.srcElement.id;

but i am getting 'Object Required' error in javaScript.

Few other things: This user control will be loaded in default.aspx page and the JS Function i am writing in default.aspx.

I am not sure why this is not working. I am using IE6/7, VS 2005. Is there any other function or way available to get the srcElement.id. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Try passing `this` along when you invoke the method

```
lnkButton.NavigateUrl = "javascript:JS_Click(this);";
```

then you can write this in your JS_Click event

```
function JS_Click(obj)
{
    alert("Now I have my object " + obj.id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use jQuery and wire up to the `click` event on your link buttons.

Add a `CssClass` attribute to the `LinkButton`'s you are creating:

```
HyperLink lnkButton = new HyperLink(); 
lnkButton.ID = "lnkButton_" + ID.ToString(); 
lnkButton.Text = tstText; 
lnkButton.CssClass = "linkButton";
```

Then write the follwoing JS/ JQuery in your ASPX page:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.linkButton', '#userControlID').click(function(e)
    {
        alert('You clicked linkbutton with ID ' + e.target.id);
    });
});
```

In the above example each link button has class="linkButton" and they are contained within your usercontrol with ID="userControlID".